# Elementary OS 6 installation without grub boot-loader

Tags: grub, macbook, install, odin, refind

In previous version of "elementary OS" there was the possibility to launch the installation of the OS from the terminal with the command "ubiquity -b". The "-b" option avoided the installation of the GRUB boot-loader.
As far as I understood elementary OS 6 does not use "ubiquity" installer anymore but uses the "io.elementary.installer" installer. Does anyone know if there is an option to launch this installer avoiding the installation of the GRUB boot-loader? Or is there any other way to avoid this installation? I am asking because I am trying to install elemetary OS on my old macbook, where I have installed "rEFInd".

Thank you

Marco

Answer (score 1):

I opened a terminal console and ran:
sudo apt install ubiquiti
Then:
ubiquity -b
I managed to run the installation and was able to boot it but it throws a problem with the password. It does not recognize the password, even though it is typed correctly. I guess it must be because I used ubiquiti as installer.

If someone knows what is the modifier of io.elementary.installer to install it without the bootloader would be very useful.

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)